# Entity framework data annotation of foreign key without a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have the following table definition:

```
public partial class ClientClassification
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public ClientClassificationEnum ClientClassificationType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

**ClientId** is a foreign key into the **Client** table. This is a many to 1 relationship (a client can have many classifications). Is there any way I can omit the **Client** navigation property but still declare this foreign key relationship? So something like:

```
public partial class ClientClassification
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Client.ClientId")]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public ClientClassificationEnum ClientClassificationType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Anybody got any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since there will be no relationship between "classes" and still you want to create the relationship on the dtaabase, I would be using a migration script to do it (and no annotations on the class).

If you would still like to have the annotation on the class (for a reason that I can't imagine right now) you could then declare a protected Client attribute (this way you would be declaring the Client navigation property but it wouldn't be accessible for anyone but inherited classes).